# 2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' while scraping thousands of records in multiprocessing

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

*Note: Before someone suggests  existing solutions, allow me to tell you respectfully that I already looked at various solutions, my error message might be the same but not the problem and the current implementation itself so allow me to explain my issue*

I am using multiprocessing to spawn multiple processes to scrape multiple URLs at once. In order to store data, I am using MySQL and using a single connection created in `__main__` during the entire execution. After a certain period of time, my script gets stuck. When I run the query `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE DB = "ecom_trends_db";` I find a SLEEP entry of various seconds. In order to deal with that I did the following when fetching links in the loop:

`connection.ping(reconnect=True)`

in the `__main__` while I am fetching the connection the first time I did the following:

```py
connection = get_connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SET  interactive_timeout = 180;')
    cursor.execute('SET  wait_timeout = 180;')
    cursor.execute('SET  net_read_timeout = 180;')
    cursor.execute('SET  GLOBAL connect_timeout = 180;')
connection.commit()
```

But still, things get stuck for a long time and I have to kill the script. If I do not kill the script, the SLEEP query time is increased and I just can't do any operation on the table where the data is being inserted. The entire code structure is given below. I am not sure whether this is something related to MySQL driver(pymysql) or something else.

```py
import pymysql


def store_parsed(url, name, location, avg_review, sales, admirers, rating, review_count, year):
    try:
        if connection is not None:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                logging.info('INSERT QUERY for URL = ' + url)
                sql = 'INSERT INTO {} (url,name, location, average_review, sales, admirers, rating, review_count,etsy_since) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'.format(
                    TABLE_PARSE)
                cursor.execute(sql, (url, name, location, avg_review, sales, admirers, rating, review_count, year))

                # Update the status of URL in shop_links
                logging.info('UPDATE QUERY for URL = ' + url)
                sql = "UPDATE {} set status = 3 where url = '{}' ".format(TABLE_FETCH, url)
                cursor.execute(sql)
                connection.commit()
                print('Data Commit')
                logging.info('Data Commit')
    except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
        print('Lost Connection in store_parsed. Pinging Now')
        # connection.ping(True)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception in store_parsed')
        crash_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S")
        crash_string = "".join(traceback.format_exception(etype=type(ex), value=ex, tb=ex.__traceback__))
        exception_string = '[' + crash_date + '] - ' + crash_string + '\n'
        print(exception_string)
        logging.warning('Exception in store_parsed')
        logging.error(exception_string)


def parse(url):
    # parsing stuff
    store_parsed(url, name, location, avg_review, sales, admirers, rating, review_count, year)


def get_links(size=100):
    total_links = []
    _links = []

    try:
        if connection is not None:
            connection.ping(reconnect=True)
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(url) from {} WHERE STATUS = 0 LIMIT {}'.format(TABLE_FETCH, size)
                cursor.execute(sql)
                links = cursor.fetchall()

                for link in links:
                    # total_links.append('https://hotpads.com{}'.format(link['url'].strip()))
                    total_links.append(link['url'].strip())
                    _links.append(link['url'].strip())
                print('Total = {}'.format(len(_links)))
            format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(links))

            if len(total_links) > 0:
                if connection is not None:
                    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                        sql = " UPDATE " + TABLE_FETCH + " set status = 1 WHERE url IN (%s)" % format_strings
                        cursor.execute(sql, tuple(_links))
                connection.commit()
                print('Affected UPDATED ROWS Rows:- {0}'.format(cursor.rowcount))


def get_connection(host, user, password, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                     user=user,
                                     password=password,
                                     db=db_name,
                                     charset='utf8',
                                     max_allowed_packet=1073741824,
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        print('Connected')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = None
    connection = get_connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SET  interactive_timeout = 180;')
        cursor.execute('SET  wait_timeout = 180;')
        cursor.execute('SET  net_read_timeout = 180;')
        cursor.execute('SET  GLOBAL connect_timeout = 180;')
    connection.commit()

    while True:
        print('Getting Links')
        logging.info('Getting Links')
        links = get_links(LIMIT)
        if len(links) == 0:
            break
        if len(links) > 0:
            with Pool(POOL_COUNT) as p:
                result = p.map(parse, links)
```

Should I create multiple connections but it will be another issue. How do I deal with it?

After decreasing timeout it was throwing the following exception:

```
Data Stored
=============END====================
Getting Links
[2022-08-16 20:08:17] - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_bytes
    data = self._rfile.read(num_bytes)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_db.py", line 69, in get_links
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 692, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 740, in _read_bytes
    "Lost connection to MySQL server during query (%s)" % (e,),
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([Errno 54] Connection reset by peer)')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_db.py", line 250, in <module>
    reset_count(connection)
  File "parse_db.py", line 17, in reset_count
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 547, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 793, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError(0, "")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, It took a LONG time to track it down, but MySQL was running out of connection because every connection was a new one. I finally ran across dbutils and it's 100% saved my bacon. I used connection pooling.

import pymysql

from dbutils.pooled_db import connect

The rest is readily describbed here
https://webwareforpython.github.io/DBUtils/main.html

At least give it a try. I can post some code if it helps

Also, setting those timeouts and other globals should be done in your mysql.conf file, I have never had any luck setting them via a sql execution from the client side.

Check your aborted clients | connections

root@server:~# mysqladmin ext | grep Abort

| Aborted_clients   | 23341
| Aborted_connects  | 0

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Were you using Python multiprocessing?

Comment: I will sure give it a try but I was not creating a new connection everytime. My problem is that I have a single global connection which times out as  I am scraping loads of data.

Comment: DBUtils may still help you then, as you can use the PersistentDB call and it should keep you alive. YOu may also have to adjust some of your timing in teh server, Specifically.

#
# * Timeouts Configuration
#
max_connections        = 1000
wait_timeout           = 120
interactive_timeout    = 300
connect_timeout        = 300
net_read_timeout       = 300
net_write_timeout      = 300


SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';

will show you the current settings. Also check the max_execution _time

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time